# Increase bar width xlsxwriter chart

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I've been trying to increase the bar width of my bar chart generated with xlsxwriter and pandas excelwriter.

This is my code:

```
import pandas
import sys

path = sys.argv[1]
df = pandas.read_csv(path, sep = "\t")
df = df[pandas.notnull(df['response_time'])]
df = pandas.pivot(df.datetime, df.name + '-' + df.type, df.response_time)
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('graph.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
df.to_csv(writer, sheet_name = "graph")
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets["graph"]

chart = workbook.add_chart({'type' : 'column'})

for i in range(1, len(df.columns) + 1):
    chart.add_series({
        'name' : ['graph', 0, i],
        'values' : ['graph', 1, i, len(df.index), i],
        'categories': ['graph', 1, 0, len(df.index), 0],
        'gap': 5
    })

chart.set_x_axis({'name' : 'DateTime'})
chart.set_y_axis({'name' : 'Response Time'})
worksheet.insert_chart('D4', chart)

writer.save()
```

This is the output graph:

[image]

The columns are to small, I would like to increase their width (I don't care if they overlap each other) but I can't find anything in the xlsxwriter documentation.

Comment: make the gap higher, like 50

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to increase their width

The first question that comes to mind is how would you do this in Excel?

If you want to do it by setting the overlap and gap for the chart series then you can do it with the `overlap` and `gap` properties of [`chart.set_series()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/chart.html?highlight=overlap#chart-add-series)